# Add 10000 days to a date

Tags: c++, datetime

I'm currently doing old exams from my course to train for my upcoming exam. What I'm wondering is about a code block which I will specify after I've presented the different files with code.

#### //`upggift1.cc` aka the main

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date d1;
    bool create_date_again = true;
    int temp_date[3];
    char garbage;
    cout << "Enter a date: ";
    cin >> temp_date[0];
    cin >> garbage;
    cin >> temp_date[1];
    cin >> garbage;
    cin >> temp_date[2];

    while (create_date_again)
    {
        try
        {
            Date date{temp_date[0], temp_date[1], temp_date[2]};
            d1 = date;

            create_date_again = false;
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            cout << "invalid date, enter another date: ";
            cin >> temp_date[0];
            cin >> garbage;
            cin >> temp_date[1];
            cin >> garbage;
            cin >> temp_date[2];
            
            create_date_again = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i{}; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        d1.tomorrow();
    }

    cout << "10000 days later: ";
    d1.print(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

#### //`date.h`

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <ostream>

class Date
{
public:
    Date();
    Date(int const y, int const m, int const d);

    bool is_leap_year() const;

    int days_in_month() const;

    void print(std::ostream& os) const;

    void tomorrow();

private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    void increment();
};
#endif
```

#### //`date.cc`

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

Date::Date()
    : year{}, month{}, day{}
{
}

Date::Date(int const y, int const m, int const d)
    : year{y}, month{m}, day{d}
{
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    {
        throw std::domain_error{"Month " + std::to_string(month) + " doesn't exist!"};
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > days_in_month())
    {
        throw std::domain_error{"Day " + std::to_string(day) + " invalid"};
    }
}

int Date::days_in_month() const
{
    static constexpr const std::array<int, 13> days{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        return 0;

    if (month == 2 && is_leap_year())
        return 29;

    return days.at(month);
}

bool Date::is_leap_year() const
{
    if (year % 400 == 0)
        return true;
    if (year % 100 == 0)
        return false;

    return year % 4 == 0;
}

void Date::print(std::ostream &os) const
{
    os << year;
    if (month < 10)
    {
        os << "-0" << month;
    }
    else
    {
        os << "-" << month;
    }
    if (day < 10)
    {
        os << "-0" << day;
    }
    else
    {
        os << "-" << day;
    }
    os << endl;
}

void Date::tomorrow()
{
    day++;
    if (is_leap_year())
    {
        if (day > 29 && month == 2)
        {
            day = 1;
            month++;
            return;
        }
        if (month != 2)
        {
            increment();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        increment();
    }
}
void Date::increment()
{
    if (day > days_in_month())
    {
        day = 1;
        month++;
    }
    if (month > 12)
    {
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
}
```

This is the part I'm particularly unsure about (`uppgift1.cc` file):

```
while (create_date_again)
    {
        try
        {
            Date date{temp_date[0], temp_date[1], temp_date[2]};
            d1 = date;

            create_date_again = false;
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            cout << "invalid date, enter another date: ";
            cin >> temp_date[0];
            cin >> garbage;
            cin >> temp_date[1];
            cin >> garbage;
            cin >> temp_date[2];
            
            create_date_again = true;
        }
    }
```

This is how I'm supposed to execute the program, and what is going to happen.

```
./a.out 
Enter a date:2013-13-02
Invalid date, enter another date:2013-12-42
Invalid date, enter another date:1900-02-29
Invalid date, enter another date:1987-04-13
10000 days later: 2014-08-29
```

My solution to keep making a new date until it's in the right format, is the `while` loop with `try`-`catch` block inside. Is that a solid solution?

I came across the problem that I wanted to create my date inside the `try`-`catch`, but then its scope doesn't allow use after the `catch`. My solution to that was to create `d1` in the main function, but I feel like this is kind of wonky? Is there any better way to solve that problem?

Much of the code in the header and implantation files are given and/or should be very similar. Feel free to give my any other advance if you want to and thank you very much if you've spent your time with this!

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I see you have edited the title, but it still seems to be focused on the _mechanism_ of the program, rather than its _purpose_.  Please re-read [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and then edit accordingly.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: I would use the standard date time functions. Normally you would store the date as seconds from the epoc. Then getting the next day is simply adding `60*60*24` seconds. Adding a thousand days is `1000*60*60*24`. Then you only need to convert it into year/month/day when you print it (there are functions for this already).

Comment: (@MartinYork: Sure, but how on earth do you add *10000* days?!?!!!!!)

Comment: The way to validate "text date"s would seem to depend on the context of the loop presented. Which you don't present, almost a day after [being referred to *How do I ask a good question?*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/257389/add-10000-days-to-a-date#comment508398_257389)

Comment: @greybeard `timeSinceEpoch += 10'000 * 60 * 60 * 24;`

Answer (score 4):

### `upggift1.cc`

Please don't do this:

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

We have namespaces for good reason, and it's a bad habit to throw away their benefits like that.

> ```
> Date d1;
> bool create_date_again = true;
> int temp_date[3];
> char garbage;
> ```

This looks like something written by a (quite old) C programmer.  Prefer to declare variables where they can be initialised, rather than all at the head of the block like this.  It looks like `temp_date` should be three individual variables, since we never actually use them as an array.

> ```
> cout << "Enter a date: ";
> ```

We should be more specific with the message, as users will expect to be able to enter a date in their own locale's usual format, e.g. 19th March 2021, but we require a much more specific format here.

> ```
> cin >> temp_date[0];
> cin >> garbage;
> cin >> temp_date[1];
> cin >> garbage;
> cin >> temp_date[2];
> ```

There's no check whether all the inputs were successfully converted.  So we don't know whether all four variables were assigned.

> ```
>     catch (const std::exception &e)
> ```

Why are we catching such a broad range of exceptions?  In particular, this will catch `std::bad_alloc` and provide a very poor response to it.

> ```
>     catch (const std::exception &e)
>     {
>         cout << "invalid date, enter another date: ";
>         cin >> temp_date[0];
>         cin >> garbage;
>         cin >> temp_date[1];
>         cin >> garbage;
>         cin >> temp_date[2];
>         
>         create_date_again = true;
>     }
> ```

Here, we have a repetition of code we've already written.  We shouldn't need to write this input again.  And there's still no check for non-numeric input or end of file (giving an infinite loop when I run the program with no input).

And why are we assigning to `create_date_again` the same value that we already know it contains?

---

### `date.h`

> ```
> #include <ostream>
> ```

It's better to include `<iosfwd>` when we only need the declarations.

> ```
> Date();
> ```

Is it a good idea to have a default constructor?  That requires a lot of logic in all functions to handle a default-constructed (invalid) date properly.  It's better to use `std::optional` where code needs the concept of "Not a date".

> ```
> Date(int const y, int const m, int const d);
> ```

Declaring the formal parameters `const` here has no effect, and is therefore just useless clutter.

> ```
> void print(std::ostream& os) const;
> ```

We would normally provide `operator<<()` instead, for easier use.

> ```
> void tomorrow();
> ```

That's a poor name for a function that modifies the instance.

---

### `date.cc`

> ```
> if (month < 1 || month > 12)
> {
>     throw std::domain_error{"Month " + std::to_string(month) + " doesn't exist!"};
> ```

I think `std::invalid_argument` is a more logical choice there.  `std::domain_error` is more suited to mathematical operations (e.g. matrix inversion).

When we catch the exception in `main()`, we ought to be extracting and displaying the message to help the user.  Otherwise we've just wasted our effort constructing a meaningful message.

> ```
> bool Date::is_leap_year() const
> {
>     if (year % 400 == 0)
>         return true;
>     if (year % 100 == 0)
>         return false;
>
>     return year % 4 == 0;
> }
> ```

That's probably the least efficient way to write this condition.  Test the most likely case first:

```
bool Date::is_leap_year() const
{
    if (year % 4)
        return false;
    if (year % 100)
        return true;
    return year % 400 == 0;
}
```

> ```
> if (month < 10)
> {
>     os << "-0" << month;
> }
> else
> {
>     os << "-" << month;
> }
> ```

Instead of that `if`/`else` stuff, just use stream formatting to use 2 digits, zero-filled:

```
os << '-' << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << month;
```

> ```
> os << endl;
> ```

Avoid `std::endl` - just use plain `\n` and let the caller decide when the stream needs to be flushed.

> ```
> day++;
> ```

Prefer pre-increment when the value isn't used.  Although it makes no difference with `int`, being consistent makes it easy for the reader.

`tomorrow()` seems over-complicated, particularly since we already have `days_in_month()` whose logic we seem to be repeating.

---

Here's something simpler and more robust:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

static Date get_date(std::istream& is = std::cin, std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{
    for (;;) {
        os << "Enter a date (y-m-d): ";
        char separator;
        int year, month, day;
        is >> year >> separator >> month >> separator >> day;
        if (!is) {
            // discard the erroneous input line
            is.clear();
            is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            if (is.eof()) {
                throw std::ios_base::failure("Stream read failure");
            }
            os << "Invalid format.";
            continue;
        }
        try {
            return {year, month, day};
        } catch (std::invalid_argument& e) {
            os << e.what() << "  ";
            // and go round again
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    try {
        auto date = get_date();
        for (auto i = 0;  i < 10000;  ++i) {
            date.advance();
        }
        std::cout << "10000 days later: " << date << '\n';
    } catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <iosfwd>

class Date
{
public:
    Date(int y, int m, int d);

    bool is_leap_year() const;
    int days_in_month() const;

    void advance();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& date);

private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};
#endif
```

```
#include "date.h"
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

Date::Date(int const y, int const m, int const d)
    : year{y}, month{m}, day{d}
{
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"Month " + std::to_string(month) + " doesn't exist!"};
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > days_in_month()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"Day " + std::to_string(day) + " doesn't exist!"};
    }
}

int Date::days_in_month() const
{
    constexpr std::array days{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    if (month == 2 && is_leap_year())
        return 29;

    return days.at(month);
}

bool Date::is_leap_year() const
{
    return year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 || year % 400 == 0;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& date)
{
    return
        os << date.year
           << '-' << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << date.month
           << '-' << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << date.day;
}

void Date::advance()
{
    ++day;
    if (day <= days_in_month()) {
        return;
    }
    ++month;
    day = 1;
    if (month <= 12) {
        return;
    }
    ++year;
    month = 1;
}
```

With this version, I've separated out a `get_date()` function.  We can test that independently.  Normally, I'd use one of the common unit-test frameworks for testing, but we can cobble together something quite simple for this:

```
#include <sstream>

// return error count - 0 on success
int test_fail(const std::string& input)
{
    std::istringstream is{input};
    std::ostringstream os{};
    try {
        Date d = get_date(is, os);
        // shouldn't get here
        std::cerr << "FAIL: \"" << input
                  << "\" produced " << d
                  << " instead of failure.\n";
        return 1;
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure&) {
        // as expected
        return 0;
    }
}

int test_succeed(const std::string& input)
{
    std::istringstream is{input};
    std::ostringstream os{};
    try {
        get_date(is, os);
        // as expected
        return 0;
    } catch (std::ios_base::failure&) {
        // shouldn't get here
        std::cerr << "FAIL: \"" << input
                  << "\" raised exception.\n";
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int errors =
        + test_fail("")
        + test_fail("not a date")
        + test_succeed("not a date\n2000-01-01")
        + test_fail("0-0-0")
        + test_fail("2000-01-0")
        + test_succeed("2000-01-01")
        + test_succeed("2000 01 01")
        + test_succeed("2000+01+01")
        + test_succeed("2000O01O01") // do we really want to allow this??
        + test_succeed("2000-01-31")
        + test_fail("2000-01-32")
        + test_succeed("2000-02-29")
        + test_fail("2000-02-30")
        + test_succeed("2004-02-29")
        + test_fail("2004-02-30")
        + test_succeed("2001-02-28")
        + test_fail("2001-02-29")
        + test_succeed("2100-02-28")
        + test_fail("2100-02-29")
        ;
    if (errors == 1) {
        std::cerr << "There was one test failure.\n";
    } else if (errors) {
        std::cerr << "There were " << errors << " test failures.\n";
    }
    return errors > 0;
}
```

The testing for the date addition can easily be incorporated into this framework.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to compute a date 10,000 days from now, I would strongly recommend using the `std::chrono` facilities.  If you do, the code would be only a few lines long:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto later{system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now() + days(10'000))};
    std::cout << "10,000 days from now the date will be "
              << std::put_time(std::localtime(&later), "%F") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but as I stated in my description, because many of the files must be in a certain way and atleast exist, this will not be an alternative. One goal of the assignment is train our logic by creating our own function. Your solution is more of a training in memory/googling to find the right #include, I'd guess.

Comment: I'd like to think of it instead as using the most appropriate tool.  If I were writing production code, it would look like this (or would use the even more capable [`std::chrono::year_month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day) with a C++20 compliant compiler and library).  "Reinventing the wheel" is, however, sometimes a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

It's not common practice to use exceptions when validating user input.  A simpler approach would be for the `Date` class to provide a static member function to check whether it's constructible from the given arguments:

```
class Date
{
public:
    static is_valid(int y, int m, int d);
    Date(int y, int m, int d);
```

Then instead of `throw`/`catch`, we can read input until `Date::is_valid()` returns true, and then proceed.

If we want better error messages, we could split the function:

```
    static is_valid_month(int y, int m, int d);
    static is_valid_day(int y, int m, int d);
```

Comment: I will look into that :)